# How do I define a folder for music videos?

Tags: windows, kodi

I have a bunch of music videos stored locally in a single directory. I want XBMC to recognize them as music videos as such, i.e. separate from existing video categories of movies/TV shows, or as just music (audio). Is this possible?

To clarify, let's say I add my directory under 'videos'. I can only set the content as either movies or as TV shows, when it's neither.
If I add the directory under 'music', it has no option to set content, and probably expects audio files there (which there aren't).

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually asking about Windows 8.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so :)